# Why does WM_CLOSE/DESTROY only partially close my Notepad window?

Tags: winapi, notepad

My scenario is that a program calls my DLL and I use `Process.Start(notepad)` to start a Notepad window on Windows 10 x64. I don't save the process ID of the started process. Then sometime later, a program calls my DLL again, and I find the Notepad window handle (by matching title strings).

The problem is that when I use the handle to send the window a WM_CLOSE or DESTROY message, the job isn't completed. The window does disappear from my screen. It does disappear from the taskbar. But when I look at windows with Alt-TAB, there it is. It's not really gone; it's just hidden from the taskbar. I'm using this Win32 API call to try to close the window.

```
[DllImport ("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool CloseWindow (IntPtr hWnd);
```

(1) What am I doing wrong?

(2) Are my expectations out of line? Is it even possible for me (as a DLL running under one process) to order Notepad in another process to close?

I suppose, having the Notepad handle in hand, that I could bring it to the foreground and send Alt+F4 to its keyboard buffer somehow to fake it into thinking that I was typing characters to it. But, that seems like the long way around.

(3) How can I programmatically tell apps to close their windows without bringing them to the foreground and sending them keystrokes, or without sending them mouse clicks on the X close button?

I've looked at other posts on the forum, but they mostly talk about terminating the process with the process APIs - a brute force kill method that isn't really what I want to do. (Besides, I want to close the single window that I'm interested in, not a whole process that might be running a dozen different windows like MS Word...)

Comment: This sort of hacking is probably going to require different approaches for different programs. Is Notepad really your target?

Comment: Notepad is indeed one of my targets. I use voice recognition to give an order to start apps, switch to apps, close windows, send text, etc. Closing an app -- any app, I hope -- is one of the desired operations.

Comment: Why don't you use UIAutomation? After all, that is the platform automation API

Comment: Thank you for the reference to UIAutomation - I had never heard of it. Lots of material to read up on there, from what I can see. I'll do more reading to see how I might be able to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using [CloseWindow] to try to close the window.

[`CloseWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632678(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't close a window -- it minimizes it.

Instead, send the window a `WM_CLOSE` message:

```
SendMessage(h, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
```

Comment: That would explain the action. I will try your suggestion to SendMessage. (I'm not feeling smart right now, after reading Petzold and tons of posts and code on the topic. I always thought `CloseWindow` sent the WM_CLOSE message for me, and that it would fall through in the WndProc to destroy the window nicely. I'll report back here on what I find. thank you

Comment: Try my suggestion, Kevin, it has broader application. @DavidHeffernan That _did_ work (when sending WM_CLOSE failed, for example) for the on-screen keyboard (which runs elevated / privileged).

Comment: I will dutifully try your suggestion, no question about that. There's so much to learn and so little time (this is a hobby project that gets leftover hours, unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
SendMessage (hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);  // or PostMessage perhaps better
```

This is what Windows sends when you click on the Close box and is much more likely to work in a wider range of apps since the app will then believe that it has been closed by the user and should act accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Paul - I will try that method too. It's clear I need to go back to my Petzold book and dig into the WM_* messages more, now that I can see the difference between sending messages and calling APIs such as `CloseWindow`.

Comment: PostMessage is async, if I recall correctly, whereas my calling app must wait for a response with SendMessage. Now I must figure out how to say "Don't save" to the dialog box that pops up when I WM_CLOSE notepad.

Comment: The advantage of using `PostMessage` is that it won't hang the calling application if the target app is unresponsive for any reason.  You can also use `SendMessageTimeout` if you want to know when the target application has processed the message but don't want to hang for ever if it never gets back to you.  Good luck with the popup.

Comment: I did more reading on the net about PostMessage (which appealed to me for the very reasons you mention) but the word is not to use it because it doesn't reset keyboard state and can be confused by international keyboards/languages, etc. I think I read it on Raymond Chen's site. `SendInput` was the recommended route to simulate input to the active app that had focus. I guess the Save popup would have the focus, so SendInput should work for that. (I'd rather send it a message directly if I can. Maybe I can identify it from the handle of the parent app somehow.

Comment: Paul, I just tried the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` method above, and it works fine too. I removed one of the trailing 0 parameters because `SendMessage` takes four arguments and not five, as far as I know. Thank you again for your help. I'll leave the SYSCOMMAND call in place since you say it works in a wider set of cases.

Comment: Paul, I realized that `PostMessage` would indeed work for my case since I'm not trying to simulate keyboard input. And it will decouple my app from waiting around to see what the target app does with the `WM_CLOSE` order. I like that idea for robustness. My apologies that it took me three tries and two days to get around to completely testing your solution, but I got there. :-) Thank you again for your help. I think I'll ignore the popup and let the user deal with it. Who knows what apps might do with (possibly nonstandard) popups anyway.